# MVC treeview (UL & JQuery), how to save state

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a treeview (using an unordered list and JQuerys treeview) in my MVC app and i am wondering the best way to keep the nodes open and close state persisted on postback?

Comment: mike - if the answer is good, click the tick by it to mark it as correct:)

Answer (score 3):

The treeview comes with an inbuilt persistence mechanism.

```
   $(".selector").treeview({
       persist: "cookie"
    })
```

See [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview/treeview#options)

Comment: Ah... didn't realise that treeview was a plugin

Answer (score 0):

Throw the list into a cookie would be my best idea (then pull it out if it is there, otherwise show the default tree). http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

You could also send it to the database and retrieve it, but that might be a little slower...

//edit:
This might help:

http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/cookies-with-jquery-designing-collapsible-layouts/